# Output returns wrong result for number of repositories in ACR

Tags: powershell, repository, azure-container-registry

I am using the following command to get the repository list of my azure container registry.

```
Write-Host "Checking registry: $AzureRegistryName"

$RepoList = az acr repository list --name $AzureRegistryName --output table

Write-Host "Total repositories:"$RepoList.length
```

The actual number of repositories is 34. But the script output gives the total number as 36. Why does that happen?

Comment: Does the object have a `Count` option instead of `Length`? There might be some hidden repositories, can you get a list and check everything that you expect is there?

Comment: Thanks. I found the answer. There are no hidden repositories. The problem was the way I processed the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the output format of table as `--output table`, then the result will be like:

```
Result
--------
repo1
repo2
repo3
repo4
```

When the result is saved to a variable `$RepoList`, the first two elements of it will be `Result` and `-----`. Thus the length of that array will be ( actual total number of repositories) + 2.

Instead of table format, you can get the result in tsv format by specifying `--output tsv` with the `az acr` command.

It returns tab- and newline-separated values without additional formatting, keys, or other symbols. This format makes it easy to consume the output into other commands and tools that need to process the text in some form.